# Kinect freezing every few seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, freeze, frame-rate

In my application I want to read some depth frames over a span of ca. 5 seconds from the kinect v2 to do some volume measurement and reconstruction of moving objects. However, the stream keeps freezing every few seconds rendering the data useless in the worst case.

This behavior can also be observed when running the wpf depth basics example.

Strangely enough - when using kinect studio the issue is not only non existent but when the studio runs even if not connected to the kinect, the problem is fixed for the example application as well.

So obviously there is no problem with the hardware (as it works just fine when running the studio) but perhaps some kind of driver or service issue.

The same is the case when running the c++ version of the sample. The sample alone runs fine and while it is running the c# version runs fine, too.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your project's platform target is 'Any CPU' then set it to 'x64'. To do so

1. Right Click on the project (not the solution) and select properties.
2. Select 'Build' from the left manu.
3. Change 'Platform target' to 'x64'.
4. Press 'Ctrl+S' to save the configuration.
5. Run the program.

Hope it helps.

Note: My answer is based on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change anything. :(

Comment: The problem occurs when using (or copying from) the WPF Depth Basics Sample.